# Selecting data for different columns from other same SQL Server table column

Tags: sql-server, select

I have a view named as `This_View` in the form:

```
Author  CoAuthor
----------------
677     901706
677     838459
677     901706
677     1695352
677     901706
1359    1695352
...  
...
```

I have to select `Name` from another table against column i.e. `Author` and `CoAuthor` where value of `Name` for both `Author` and `CoAuthor` exist in the same column of `Other_Table`.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT name as Author, name as CoAuthor
FROM Other_Table AA
JOIN This_View YA ON YA.Author = AA.aid AND YA.CoAuthor = AA.aid
ORDER BY Author
```

but not succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to make different JOIN for Author and Coauthor

```
SELECT AA.name as Author, BB.name as CoAuthor
FROM This_View YA 
JOIN Other_Table AA ON YA.Author = AA.aid
JOIN Other_Table BB ON YA.CoAuthor = BB.aid
ORDER BY AA.name
```

Comment: @Taufel Glad it helps you :)

Comment: Hmmm...I was aware of JOIN two or more tables but not aware of JOINing same table twice differently...anyhow a new curry to my menu :)